# Posible to use mini display to HDMI with HDMI splitter?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, hdmi, mini-displayport

I have a macbook pro 13 inch with two external monitors. I'd like to set up a third external monitor however the only working ports on my laptop are the two mini-display ports. The HDMI port was damaged. My question is this: If I run a mini-display to HDMI adapter to an active HDMI splitter, for example: [something like this](http://www.cableleader.com/hdmi-amplifier-splitter-1x2-pigtail-type-with-power-adapter.html?gclid=CNrDvv3d5MUCFRSPfgodnHsAPA), will my machine still be able to detect the third monitor through the mini-display? I don't want to spend any money on something like this if it's not going to work so I was hoping someone on here knew and could help me figure that out. Also, I'd like to know if the new monitor running through the splitter, will still be able to extend the display or if I'll only be able to mirror the screens? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitters duplicate the screen they should warn you about this in their product description. I doubt this is what you want. If you want to be able to use both screens separately you are looking for a multi display adapter / multi stream transporter. Mac should have setting to mirror the display however I make no promises.

Here comes the bad news. Currently they're significantly more expensive. I know you're not using a desktop but for those who are it's likely cheaper to buy a graphics card compatible with your system.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say 100% yes or no, but there are some things you may be able to investigate to increase your confidence either way....

What is the maximum output resolution on the mini-display port. Graphics cards have seperate 'heads'. If the maximum display resolution on the head is 2x the monitor resolutions you are using, you can probably use a splitter. If not, probably not.